# Get record id in lightning component which was added to a record page

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, record

Let us suppose that I go to a record. Then I am editing its page by adding a custom component on the page.

Now I would like to be able to get a record id in the custom component which was added to the page. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You implement the force:hasRecordId interface on your component:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId">
```

From there, you can get the ID at any point:

```
doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
  var recordId = component.get("v.recordId");
  // ...
```

Do not put your own attribute called recordId in to your component; it is defined by the force:hasRecordId interface for you automatically. You can read more in [this developer blog post](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/11/building-context-aware-lightning-components.html) and [in the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:hasRecordId/documentation).

Comment: Can you also show us how to do it in the lightning web component (none aura component) please? or post a reference link that shows it? Thanks!

Comment: @Bahman.A See [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_record_context) for the LWC version.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response. You ROCK!!